# Run powershell command from context menu

Tags: windows, powershell, hash, command, contextmenu

Command = Get-FileHash .\test.png extension -Algorithm MD5.
I was able to add an item called "Hash" to the context menu. In the registry, in the command section, I execute “powershell.exe -NoExit”. When the president right-clicked on the file, a folder opened in the context menu of the president of my item, but I cannot move further.

I specified "-Command" "Get-FileHash .\1.png -Algorithm MD5" and it works, but only with the specified file. You want it to automatically point to the selected file, for example SelectedFile.ItsExtension

Comment: Try with `'%1'` in place of the file path